# Is using locking mechanism in Threading program equivalent to executing the code synchronously rather then asynchronously?

Tags: c#, locking

Example code below uses the concept of locking. But that prevents it from giving parallel execution. So is the title of the question correct:
Is using locking mechanism in Threading program equivalent to executing the code synchronously rather then asynchronously?

Does same case apply for Threading.Monitor and declaring class with [Synchronization] Attribute ??

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{    
    Console.WriteLine("*****Synchronizing Threads *****\n");  
    Printer p = new Printer();  
    // Make 10 threads that are all pointing to the same    
    // method on the same object.    
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[10]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)    
    {      
        threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(p.PrintNumbers));  
        threads[i].Name = string.Format("Worker thread #{0}", i);    
    }  
    // Now start each one.   
    foreach (Thread t in threads)  
    t.Start();   
    Console.ReadLine();
} 

public void PrintNumbers() 
{   
    // Use the private object lock token.  
    lock (threadLock)  
    {    
        // Display Thread info.
        Console.WriteLine("-> {0} is executing PrintNumbers()",Thread.CurrentThread.Name);  
        // Print out numbers.    
        Console.Write("Your numbers: "); 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  
        {      
            Random r = new Random();   
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * r.Next(5));  
            Console.Write("{0}, ", i);    
        }     
        Console.WriteLine();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is using locking mechanism in Threading program equivalent to executing the code synchronously rather then asynchronously?

Specifically in your example, you're wrapping the entire method call with a lock, so you'll experience synchronous behavior, and threading in this case would be useless and provide more overhead than gain.

Many times, you have a specific place where locking is needed when accessing shared state, and that is usually where the limit of your parallelism lays. But you may still gain computational benefits if you have a significant amount of CPU work which can be executed in parallel.

As a side note, there is a difference between asynchrony and parallalism. I'd advise you to read [this article](http://urda.cc/blog/2010/10/04/asynchronous-versus-parallel-programming/) for more on the meaning of both.

Comment: Does same case apply for Threading.Monitor and declaring class with [Synchronization] Attribute ??

Comment: The `lock` statement is syntactical sugar for `Monitor.Enter`, and `[MethodImplOptions.Synchronized]` will wrap your entire method with `lock(this)`. So yes, they are equivalent, only differentiated by the object you lock on.

Answer (score 0):

> Is using locking mechanism in Threading program equivalent to executing the code synchronously rather then asynchronously?

It combines the lack of concurrency of a synchronous program with the overheads of multi-threading to combine the worse parts of both approaches.

It is though just to demonstrate that locking forces synchronised access to particular bits of code. In real multi-threaded use one holds locks for as short a time as possible, so different threads can work simultaneously and only block each other when absolutely necessary.

Comment: Can you please share a simple use case example